# Re-Execute DB update Query When Exception Occurs

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to re-execute the query whenever SQLException occurs and sometime I get the Exception of

```
SQLException occurred... com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.
MySQLTransactionRollbackExceptionDeadlock
found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

My code is below. The database is MySQL InnoDB .. Please suggest...

```
  String sqlquery = "UPDATE tbl_users SET abill=?" 
                                 + " WHERE uid=? AND sms='2'"; 

     PreparedStatement preStatement=null;
      try{
         con.setAutoCommit(false);
        preStatement=con.prepareStatement(sqlquery);
        preStatement.setString(1,billpush);
        preStatement.setString(2,uid);
        preStatement.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
       }

     catch(SQLException sE)
     {
       log.error("SQLException occurred... "+sE);
         con.rollback();
     }
      finally {
if (preStatement != null) {
preStatement.close();
    }        
            }
```

Comment: You are having a loop in the query.. When it is 2 update to 2.. Hope you get it... DeadLock situation. So terminated..

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu.. Sorry!!  when it is 2  update to 2?? which loop?

Comment: UPDATE tbl_users SET abill=billpush, asms =2" WHERE uid="uid" AND sms='2'"; 
Did you get it?? Try With different input it will work..

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu  But I need that condition saying sms=2. and I should update his record saying sms=2, if he is failed to bill.  else his record will be updated to  sms=1  if he is successful

Comment: Please understand the logic Don't Update **1** with **1**.. My Question is if the value is 2 why are you updating again to 2 when it is already 2.
//Eg: you are saying `Madan` name is changed to `Madan`.. So the database goes for infinite loops

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu.. Yup I got you. But there can be sms=1 (successful) for other tickets of the same user. so I wanted to say update sms=2 only to those tickets which has sms=2 (unsuccessful).. If I say update sms=2 for userid=uid   then it will update all his tickets to 2 ..  even his successful tickets.. !!

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu I guess he is updating a different column asms not the same column sms. If both are same as you said it is a loop

Comment: Even if there is an infinite loop, this shouldn't cause a deadlock.

Comment: @YaK: InnoDB in MySQL will detect the deadlock.

Comment: @Vasu: The Scenario is like this `sms='2'` never gets updated to something else. so Sms=2 will be always true.. Hope He should change `sms='2'` to some thing else..

Comment: In your code, you are updating a `asms` column (notice the "a") whereas the WHERE condition is about the `sms` column. Was there a typo here or are we talking about two different columns?

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu No, an `UPDATE`, however broken, cannot be the root cause of a deadlock. The root cause of a dead lock is two concurrent transactions trying to acquire a lock on something already locked by the other transaction.

Comment: It's the same column. "sms". It shows me deadlock only in the concurrent environment.. when I run a single java file, it updates without any error..  sms can be 2,1 or 0 depending upon the billing success.. There can be different tickets of the same user having different values of sms (1,2 or 0) so I want to update only those ticket which has sms=2.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction 

Is the exception I am getting now...

Comment: Then there is certainly something wrong with your UPDATE. No need to `SET sms = 2` since there already is a `WHERE sms = 2` condition. The `UPDATE` will only modify those records already having their field at 2 (here I am just repeating what Senthil said earlier). One of these two clauses, of not both, are to be removed. But this is not the root cause of the deadlock.

Comment: @YaK : http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/08/how-to-deliberately-cause-a-deadlock-in-mysql" Just have a Look at this article It clearly states update can lead to deadlock.

Comment: (broken link, I am afraid) Of course, an update can cause a deadlock. Any statement could create a dead lock. But a broken statement cannot create a deadlock *per se*. There needs to be at least one concurrent transaction in the game.

Comment: @YaK I have updated  my query to  update tbl_users set aBill=?  where uid=? and  sms=2.   but still I get the same exception1!!!

Comment: I am sorry to repeat myself. But whether the query is broken or not is irrelevant. If you want to solve the deadlock issue, you need to list all concurrent queries that are running when the deadlock occurs. If you just want to retry after exception, please consider my answer.

Comment: @YaK: Link is : http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/08/how-to-deliberately-cause-a-deadlock-in-mysql  .I believe that the transaction cannot lock a table on close connection the lock will be released(in Java). So there is less possible for locking tables...

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tbl_users SET abill=billpush, asms ='2' WHERE uid='uid' AND sms='2' and asms<>'2'
```

This will prevent the dead lock just add a condition at the end as asms<>'2'. 
 hope this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a flag to `true` after your dangerous operation:

```
bool ok = false;

while (!ok) {
    ok = false;
    try {
        doSomethingFishy();
        ok = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        dealWithError(); // perhaps wait for a short while and increment a "retry" counter
    }
}
```